# Unexpected java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Duplicate key in ArrayMap in Xamarin

Tags: java, c#, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am getting this mystery exception in my C# Xamarin code:

```
// startTime contains DateTime.Now set earlier in code
//_progressNotification and _..Manager were set once earlier and are never null
//The various Duration variables are doubles with values  >=0 (totalDuration is never zero) 
// The following code is inside var progressHandler = new Progress<double>(p =>
    var progress = (int)Math.Round((p*video.Duration.TotalSeconds + downloadedDuration) * (100d/totalDuration));
    progress = Math.Min(progress, 100);
    progress = Math.Max(progress, 0);
    var secondsPasssed = (DateTime.Now - startTime).TotalSeconds; // For how many seconds are we downloading
    var remainingTine = (downloadedDuration + p * video.Duration.TotalSeconds) <= 0 ? "??:??:??" : TimeSpan.FromSeconds((secondsPasssed * totalDuration / (p * video.Duration.TotalSeconds + downloadedDuration)) - secondsPasssed).ToString(@"hh\:mm\:ss");
    _progressNotification.SetContentText($"{i}/{totalItemsInQueue} {remainingTine}");
    _progressNotification.SetProgress(100, progress, false);
    _notificationManager.Notify(ProgressNotificationId, _progressNotification.Build()); // This line throws the exception
```

Basically, the progress method gets executed with values between 0 - 1 (p) and then some simple math is done to calculate a progress value and then a notification to show this progress is published (updated)

It works fine most of the time, but sometimes it throws the mysterious exception mentioned above.

I can't figure out what is causing the exception to occur.

Comment: Which lines throws the exception? Post the stack trace

Comment: The exception happens on the last line. I don't have any exception details, since pretty much all exceptions I get on xamarin only mention the exception name and the details show a Timeout ("Unhandled Exception:

Java.Lang.IllegalArgumentException: <Timeout exceeded getting exception details> occurred) I wasn't able to find any setting allowing me to increase the time limit to avoid timeouts.

Comment: its not because of that, it is because of some argument that you have passed in your program